# Accessing metadata attr on template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I have a mocked api endpoint with ember-cli-mirage and with some metadata. I did override the model serializer to add that metadata like this:

```
import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    serialize(object, request) {
        let json = JSONAPISerializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

        json.meta = {
            compass_size: 1,
            arrow_size: 2,
            total: 3
        }

        return json;
    }
});
```

The api call returns that metadata correctly:

```
Object
    data: Array[10]
    meta: Object
     arrow_size: 2
     compass_size: 1
     total: 3
     ...
```

Given I have this route handler:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('events');
  }
});
```

When I try to print that data on my template

```
{{ model.meta.compass_size }}
```

then nothing is rendered. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `normalizeResponse` hook to interpret the server(mirage) response.

To change the format of the data that is sent to the backend store, you can use the `serialize()` hook. so in your case your backend(mirage) provides data in a format other than JSON API, you can use the `normalizeResponse()` hook.

[Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try it soon and accept the answer when I manage to get it working. Is strange because at some point it was working, and when I check again it was not working and never did again. I never did anything on normalizeResponse so I don't get how It got working on first place... I thought that metadata was managed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

weird thing, some times I ran into the same issue, and some times this worked for me :

`model.content.meta.compass_size`